# Does there exist $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\{\|f_n g\|_1 :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is unbounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|_\infty = \infty$. Does there exist $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\{\|f_n g\|_1 :n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is the dual space of $L^1(\mathbb R)$. So if on the contrary that $\{ \|f_n g\|_1: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded for all $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, then 
$$\left\{ \int_\mathbb{R} f_ng : n\in \mathbb N\right\}$$
is bounded for all $g$. The uniform boundedness principle implies that $\{ \| f_n\|_\infty : n\in \mathbb N\}$ is also uniformly bounded. This contradicts your assumption and so such a $g$ exists.